# Page break in an Xfinium flow document

Tags: c#, pdf, uwp

I'm creating a PdfFlowDocument using Xfinium.PDF for UWP. I need to insert a page break but only if a certain section (containing paragraphs and tables) does not fit on the current page. It's a kind of "keep together" feature.

How could I accomplish my task?

UPDATE: I've minimized the amount of content that I need to keep together to just a single table. Although it is a flow table, I understand I will need to convert it to a fixed-sized table to calculate its height. If I could somehow find out the current position on the page after rendering all flow content, I would be able to calculate how much space left on the page. If there is enough space for the table, I would render it on the page. If not, I would issue a page break and render it on the next page.

Is there a feature to find out the current position on the page after rendering the flow content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force a page break by calling PdfFlowDocument.StartNewPage.
 
Size information for flow content is not available in the public API, you cannot test in your code if a content object fits the current available space.
 
We'll support this in the next release.

Comment: That's bad news :( I have a signature section on my PDF document and I need to keep it together. It may not span two pages. I have updated my question. Maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: The only solution is to force a new page before adding this new section, no matter it fits or not the current page.

Comment: Is it possible to remove a flow element from the PdfFlowDocument? If so, this is a trick that just might work: 1) Get the number of pages through PdfFlowDocument.GetFixedDocument().Pages.Count.    2) Add the element you want to keep together     3) Check the number of pages again. If it is the same, leave the added element on the page. If the number of pages increased, it means the added element spans two pages     4) Remove the element.     5) Insert page break     6) Add the element again.    Do you think it would work?

Comment: @ata6502 flow content objects cannot be removed once they have been added

Comment: Well, I really need to keep the signature section together on a single page. If the PdfFlowDocument is not capable of delivering that, what are other options then?   I'm also a little bit disappointed in Xfinium component. I chose it over other PDF components such as Syncfusion because of the document flow capability but it seems I made a wrong decision :(

Comment: @ata6502 please open a ticket with support and we'll work this out

Comment: That sounds great :) I've invested substantial amount of time at Xfinium and rewriting all of that using a different component would be tedious. The problem is I'm still evaluating the product in order to convince CEO to purchase it. Could I still issue a ticket even? If so, how should I do it? A solution for the "keeping together" feature would help us make a decision about purchasing a license.

Comment: I have just received a patch from Xfinium that solved the problem. It looks like I made a right decision choosing Xfinium after all :)

Comment: @MihaiIancu - I've run into the same scenario as listed here.  Has this functionality been added to the core library?

Comment: @Patrick yes, information about the size of flow content is now available in the public API. PdfFlowContent.GetContentHeight method gives you the height of a flow content object.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with a single row and cell. For the cell use a *PdfFlowTableCompositeCell*. It has a property *Content* which is a collection of flow content objects. On the row set *EnableRowSplit = false*.

```
        var table = new PdfFlowTableContent(1);

        //column width in %
        table.Columns[0].Width = 100;

        var row = table.Rows.Add();
        row.EnableRowSplit = false;
        var cell = new PdfFlowTableCompositeCell();

        //text
        cell.Content.Add(new PdfFlowTextContent(new PdfFormattedContent(KswModuleTranslator.PdfFaultReportStationAssuranceText)));

        //image
        var image = new PdfPngImage(new MemoryStream(signatureData.Signature));
        var imgDings = new PdfFlowImageContent(image);
        cell.Content.Add(imgDings);

        //text
        cell.Content.Add(new PdfFlowTextContent(new PdfFormattedContent(signatureInfo.SigneeName)));

        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        document.AddContent(table);
```